# How do I stack the first two columns of a table into a single column?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, transformation

I'd like to stack two columns of a table into a single column. So for example, if the source table is:

`| Id |  Code_1 |  Code_2 | Other |
|----|---------|---------|-------|
|  1 | Value_1 | Value_2 | Row_1 |
|  2 | Value_3 |  (null) | Row_2 |
|  3 |  (null) | Value_4 | Row_3 |
|  4 |  (null) |  (null) | Row_4 |
|  5 | Value_5 |  (null) | Row_5 |`

Then the target table should be:

`| Id |    Code | Other |
|----|---------|-------|
|  1 | Value_1 | Row_1 |
|  2 | Value_2 | Row_1 |
|  3 | Value_3 | Row_2 |
|  4 | Value_4 | Row_3 |
|  5 | Value_5 | Row_5 |`

Notice that the `Other` column just duplicates its values, but only when there's a non-null value in `Code_1` and `Code_2`.

I tried to use a PIVOT statement cos I'm essentially trying to (almost) stack transposes of each row, but I can't figure out how to orchestrate it properly.

I have the DDL is below:

`CREATE TABLE Source (
  Id     INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Code_1 VARCHAR(10),
  Code_2 VARCHAR(10),
  Other  VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO Source VALUES ('Value_1', 'Value_2', 'Row_1'), ('Value_3', NULL, 'Row_2'), (NULL, 'Value_4', 'Row_3'), (NULL, NULL, 'Row_4'), ('Value_5', NULL, 'Row_5');`

`CREATE TABLE Target (
  Id    INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Code  VARCHAR(10),
  Other VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO Target VALUES ('Value_1', 'Row_1'), ('Value_2', 'Row_1'), ('Value_3', 'Row_2'), ('Value_4', 'Row_3'), ('Value_5', 'Row_5')`

Comment: You're looking for an `UNPIVOT` (the opposite of a pivot). Two ways to do this would be to use `UNPIVOT` syntax or `CROSS APPLY` the columns (e.g. `select s.other, c.col from [source] as s cross apply (values (code_1), (code_2)) as c(col) where c.col is not null;`)

Comment: Hmm, cross apply works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `unpivot`:

```
SELECT Id, Code, Other
FROM 
   Source
UNPIVOT
   (Code FOR code_ IN 
      (code_1, code_2)
) AS unpvt;
```

See the [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e28b4/7).