# How do I stack the first two columns of a table into a single column, but also pair third column with the first column only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313904/how-do-i-stack-the-first-two-columns-of-a-table-into-a-single-column) earlier, but the requirements this time are a bit more complex. I have a table that looks like the following:

```
| id | code_1 | code_2 | pair_1 |
|----|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |     a1 |     a2 |     b1 |
|  2 |     a3 |     a4 | (null) |
|  3 |     a5 | (null) |     b2 |
|  4 |     a6 | (null) | (null) |
|  5 | (null) |     a7 |     b3 |
|  6 | (null) |     a8 | (null) |
|  7 | (null) | (null) |     b4 |
|  8 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

I want to stack code_1 and code_2 into a single column, which can be done by using:

```
select id, code, pair_1 as pair
  from source
       unpivot (code for code_ in (code_1, code_2)) as unpvt;
```

, which produces the following output:

```
| id | code |   pair |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 |   a1 |     b1 |
|  1 |   a2 |     b1 |
|  2 |   a3 | (null) |
|  2 |   a4 | (null) |
|  3 |   a5 |     b2 |
|  4 |   a6 | (null) |
|  5 |   a7 |     b3 |
|  6 |   a8 | (null) |
```

, but I also want to capture the condition that `code_1` is paired with `pair_1` i.e. whenever `code` is sourced from `code_1`, it will use the value in `pair_1` for `pair`; and whenever `code` is sourced from `code_2`, it will always use `null` for `pair`.

So for example, given the original table, here is what the target table should look like:

```
| id | code |   pair |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 |   a1 |     b1 |
|  2 |   a2 | (null) |
|  3 |   a3 | (null) |
|  4 |   a4 | (null) |
|  5 |   a5 |     b2 |
|  6 |   a6 | (null) |
|  7 |   a7 | (null) |
|  8 |   a8 | (null) |
```

**DDL**:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/743a5/16

```
create table source (
  id     int identity(1, 1) primary key,
  code_1 varchar(10),
  code_2 varchar(10),
  pair_1 varchar(10)
);
insert into source values
('a1', 'a2', 'b1'),
('a3', 'a4', null),
('a5', null, 'b2'),
('a6', null, null),
(null, 'a7', 'b3'),
(null, 'a8', null),
(null, null, 'b4'),
(null, null, null);


create table target (
  id   int identity(1, 1) primary key,
  code varchar(10),
  pair varchar(10)
);
insert into target values
('a1', 'b1'),
('a2', null),
('a3', null),
('a4', null),
('a5', 'b2'),
('a6', null),
('a7', null),
('a8', null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't you do simple `UNION ALL`?

**Try query below**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT id, code_1 as code, pair_1 as pair FROM source WHERE code_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, code_2 as code, NULL as pair FROM source WHERE code_2 IS NOT NULL
) UnionTable
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This seems to work. Give me some time to test it before marking as accepted answer. Thanks!